# Boto3.setup_default_session cant find the profile name on a windows system

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-sam, botocore

I have a python 3.6 based lambda function executing locally under a SAM Local call with the following command

> `sam local start-api -d 5890 --profile my-prof --region localhost`

This is my code

```
import boto3
import boto3.session


boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="my-prof")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
  pr = boto3.session.Session().available_profiles
  profiles= 'Total profiles = '

  for session in pr:
    profiles =profiles +  'Profile: ' + session.profile
    profiles =profiles +' '

  return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": profiles + str(len(pr))   ,
         }),
  }
```

I am getting an error at this line

> boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="my-prof")

Error:

> module initialization error: The config profile (my-prof) could
>   not be found

When I comment out the line giving the error, I am able to execute the function handler and it returns 0 profiles. Why is this happening and why cant boto3 find my local profiles?

My config file looks like this

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[profile my-prof]
region = localhost
output = json
```

Credentials file looks like this

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[my-prof]
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: I think your lambda function is looking for credentials in your local container, not your host workstation.

Comment: I don't have control of the container. SAM for lambda creates the container when I call out the sam local start api command. How do I get it to look at the credentials in host? I don't want to update the container unless thats the only option forward.

Comment: I think you don't need to specify profile in your script. When you use `--profile my-prof` in `sam` cli, it will (I think) pass the credentials as default into the container. Thus you use your function as you would use in real lambda - no need to use profiles.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I've seen many  examples that use the session set in code, but they were all old examples. What is the session class used for then?

Comment: Its useful when you run your scripts on your local workstation. You can easily switch between different accounts, or when you IAM assume role. Did it work? I can provide an answer if the issue is solved?

Comment: @Marcin When I took out the line giving the error it seems to work. I am able to post data to dynamodb using the same profile. But when the line `except Exception as ex:
    print('Not working: ')` is in the code, it continues to give that error -  irrespective of whether or not I use --profile my-prof in the sam cli

Comment: there is no such line in the code you've posted. Can you update the code to its latest version. I understand the the original issue with missing profile name is solved?

Comment: @Marcin: Im sorry. That was a misprint. I actually meant an error at this line: `boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="my-prof")` The original issue seems to be my local lambda container not able to reach the aws profiles on the host machines. I'm leaving it at that for now.